# Why does QtGUI not include all GUI elements in Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I watched VoidRealm tutorial, and he easily include QtGui and start using it! but i do the same thing and it doesnt work for me! for example my code doesnt know the QWidget until i include QLabel! or all other Gui element...

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget *win = new QWidget;
    win->setWindowTitle("MBS");

    QGridLayout *gLay = new QGridLayout;

    QLabel *label1 = new QLabel("Name: ");

    win->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: in this case, Qt5 get error from me for QLabel too because i dont include QLabel in it

Comment: If you want a good reason, rather than a fix like Predelnik has given, I think that compilation time is much much faster if you only include the parts you actually use instead of the whole toolkit.

Comment: The reason is that QtGui is now the common base for QtQuick2 and QtWidgets, which have no interdependency anymore. So QtGui doesn't include anything widget-related anymore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `Qt5` most of the previously known as `QtGui` functionality now is being called `QtWidgets`.

So try to write `#include <QtWidgets>`.